# Raid 5 failure on P400i Controller

Tags: raid, hp, raid5

I was hoping for some help. My server won't boot up into Windows and I get the following errors:

1794-Slot 0 Drive Array - Array Accelerator Battery Charge low
     Array Accelerator Posted-Write Cache is temporarily disabled
     Array Accelerator batteries have failed to charge and should be replaced
1779-Slot 0 Drive Array - Replacement drive(s) detected OR previously failed drive(0) now appear to be operational: 
      Port 1l   Box1   Bay 3
      Port 2l   Box1   Bay 5
     Logical drive(s) disabled due to possible data loss.
Select "F1" to continue with logical drive(s) disabled.
Select "F2" to accept data loss and re-enable logical drive(s)

Can you please advise on whether I need to replace the battery before re-enabling the logical drive? How much data loss am I looking at? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should replace the battery before moving forward, no idea how much data you may have lost, it depends when your last backup was obviously. Also please don't use R5, it's had it's day and is now essentially dangerous.

Comment: Ok - will purchase the battery and update once fitted. I know R5 is no good - this is just a very old (but typically vital) server we haven't yet replaced.

Comment: One more question, when I've replaced the battery, does it need to charge before I go ahead and re-enable the logical drive?

Comment: Maybe give it an hour but you don't need it to be fully charged I don't think